# python pandas dates not plotting correctly

Tags: python, date, pandas, plot

Im trying to plot my data which runs from date '2015-05-01' to '2015-05-08' (1st May to 8th of May) and heres my code

```
df = pd.read_csv(myfile.csv, parse_dates=[0], dayfirst=True)
df = df.set_index('timestamp')
df.index = df.index.to_datetime()
df.sort_index(inplace=True)
```

but when I plot and limit the x-axis like

```
axs.set_xlim('2015-05-01','2015-05-08')
```

i get the following figure

[image]

which is missing days where data exists, for example if run the code

```
df[3000:3005]
```

I see

```
                          A
     timestamp  
2015-03-05 13:51:00    71.000000
2015-03-05 13:52:00    71.600000
2015-03-05 13:53:00    72.500000
2015-03-05 13:54:00    73.142857
2015-03-05 13:55:00    77.625000
```

I think its becuase it thinks 2015-03-05 is the 5th of March, but its really the 3rd of May.

So how can i get the plot to show the data for YYYY-DD-MM and not YYYY-MM-DD?

EDIT: my raw data is like

```
05/03/2015 07:37    60.6
05/03/2015 07:38    59.33333333
05/03/2015 07:39    65.625
05/03/2015 07:40    68.33333333
05/03/2015 07:41    61
```

and im using the following code to plot

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(1,1, figsize=(15,4))
axs.plot( df.index, df.A , '*')
axs.legend(loc='lower right', prop={'size':19})
axs.set_xlim('2015-05-01','2015-05-08')
axs.set_ylim(0,200)
fig.show()
```

and using

```
axs.set_xlim('01-05-2015','08-05-2015')
```

gives

[image]

Comment: The displayed datetime format is the default, if you want to set your limits correctly then you need to change the passed in datetime string: `axs.set_xlim('2015-01-05','2015-08-05')` pandas is not going to interpret your passed in datetime as month first. Also what does the raw data look like?

Comment: so I guess in my dataframe I just need o switch around the dates like for 2015-03-05 make it 2015-05-03

Comment: Well if your dates were passed correctly, what you're seeing will be YYYY-MM-DD as the displayed output, passed in datetime strings will also be interpreted like that but without a sample of your raw data I can't confirm 100% but this is expected behaviour

Comment: just edited the post to include the raw data

Comment: @RunnerBean What are you using to plot this?

Comment: I've tested against your data and the code is correct can you post your code that plots this. Also can you try `axs.set_xlim('01-05-2015','08-05-2015')` I think that when you pass datetime strings in your format the last component is treated is month rather than day

Comment: just updated to show plot code

Comment: So did my last comment help?

Comment: no, ive updated the question to show the result of your last comment

Comment: I don't think you need the to_datetime line

Comment: just removed that line and tried again but problem still persists

Comment: try `df.plot()` which uses pandas plotting API and will handle the dates in DatetimeIndex for you